# configure sharepoint online search

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, search-box

I am having a problem with Search online. when user enters a text like this in search box, eg. ABC-1, does not get any results back. But when user enters ABC- then the result is returned.

Any idea how to make it possible to search even if user enters a minus sign (-) which is part of the filename?

Comment: The only purpose for "-" in a query is to negate everything that comes after the "-". So your query is "ABC NOT 1"

Answer (score 0):

The search  indexer treats "-" as a word-breaker, meaning that the index doesn't
keep "ABC-1" as a single word "ABC". 
The only way to change this is creating a custom word breaker. However, as you are using SharePoint Online, I am afraid that it is impossible to do.

As a workaround, I suggest you avoid using "-" in file name.